# How exactly does the css in the John Doe no-js webpage manage to make the default home section disappear?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking at this nice minimal web template: https://john-doe.neocities.org/  (github here: https://github.com/cadars/john-doe/)

This uses the section tag and the :target selector to elegantly create no-js 'tabs' that make one particular section visible while hiding all others in the page.

I tried to reproduce this for my site, via the following, simplified css:

```
section { display: none; }
section:target { display: block; }
section#home { display:block;}
```

However, this does not have the desired effect, since, while it does indeed achieve the effect that the 'default' section will show up in the absence of a #reference in the url, however it does not hide it when another reference is specified. In other words, the section with the 'home' id is *always* displayed, whether it is the target or not.

Whereas in the John Doe page, you will see that if any other target is selected, the #home section is replaced. And if *no* section is selected (i.e. the URL does not contain a "#" reference), the #home element is indeed visible by default.

I have studied the css style on the John Dow website, but I cannot really see what is the difference between my css and John Doe's that makes their default #home section behave as expected. Can someone help me figure it out?

Here is a simple testcase:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      section { display: none; }
      section:target { display: block; }
      section#first { display: block; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="first" > First (default) section </section>
    <section id="second"> Second section          </section>
    <section id="third" > Third section           </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That’s where the `position: absolute;` comes in. The `#home` is underneath the other sections. Inspect the element and see the applied styles. To explain more generally, _why_ your example doesn’t work: it’s because `section#home` has a much higher specificity than `section:target`, and so gets higher precedence. Try [`section:where(#home)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where) which doesn’t affect specificity.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I see ... so it's not really 'hidden', it's 'covered' by another element? So if the 'home' element was large enough it would show below the other one?

Comment: Is there a way to achieve that result using css without this 'cover' trick?

Comment: See my edited comment: `:where` can be helpful (if supported). I’m not sure what happens if `#home` is very large.

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks, I'll have a look. I was just looking at the css, I think the author uses a min-height that ensures the #home element will be covered at all times.

Comment: Can’t get it to work with `:where`, but the answer below gives two good alternatives. Not sure an answer simply saying _“They use `position: absolute;`”_ is substantial enough. Maybe it can be edited into the existing answer.

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks again for your comments. Sorry, I accepted the current answer since this seems to be what I was after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```css
section:target {
  display: block; /* show the targetted one */
}

section:target ~ section, /* all the section after the targetted one hidden*/
section { /* all of them hidden */
  display: none;
}

section:last-of-type {
  display: block; /* last one visible */
}
```

```html
<section id="second"> Second section </section>
<section id="third"> Third section </section>
<section id="first"> First (default) section </section> <!-- must be the last one -->
<div style="position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;">
  <a href="#first">first</a>
  <a href="#second">second</a>
  <a href="#third">third</a>
</div>
```

Or like below:

```css
section:target {
  display: block;
}

section:target ~ section:not(#random),
section {
  display: none;
}

section#first {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section id="second"> Second section </section>
<section id="third"> Third section </section>
<section id="first"> First (default) section </section> <!-- must be not the first one (at least one section before it) -->
<div style="position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;">
  <a href="#first">first</a>
  <a href="#second">second</a>
  <a href="#third">third</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. Would you mind adding a small explanation on each? I take it the order of sections is necessary?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou yes the order is necessary to be able to use `~` so that I can select the default section when a previous one is targetted then specificity will strike